# Name of maths technique?

Tags: probability-theory, fractions, machine-learning

I'm currently looking at runs of identical outputs, and looking at the fractions I get back. When I was running through it, I had a feeling I'd come across something similar before, and it would be really useful to be able to use the actual mathematical technique if there is one, but I don't know what I'm looking for. Can anyone point me in the right direction? The idea is as follows:

I have two vectors, for simplicity, they are

{A, B, B, C, C, C}, and {A, A, B, B, C, C}.

I'm looking at them different ways, but really it's:

A=A, B!=A, B=B, C!=B, C=C, C=C,

which gives

1/6, 1/6, 2/6 - the overall fraction of consecutive True statements,

while comparing with the fraction of True statements:

1/4, 1/4, 2/4

and then possibly looking at the difference between the consecutive fractions and the consecutive overall:

1/4 % 1/6 = 1.5

I'm sorry I'm explaining this badly, I hope the example helps. Is there a theory I should look at? Or some rule for weighting in Machine Learning etc?

Comment: The final number, $3/2$, that you've computed, is just the length of your vectors divided by the number of true statements. It no longer has anything to do with whether or not those true statements were consecutive.

Comment: Thanks @MeesdeVries , I understand that, I was hoping to use the final results as a weighting of sorts, and I think I've seen something similar before, I just can't remember in what context. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.